# Timespan can not Convert.ToInt16(elapsedSeconds)) and can not Convert.ToInt64(elapsedSeconds)) Error Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an error while try convert variable elapseseconds to ToInt16 and ToInt64.

```
TimeSpan cTime = new TimeSpan (0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt16(elapsedSeconds));
```

Got an error :

```
OverflowException: Value is greater than Int16.MaxValue or less than Int16.MinValue
System.Convert.ToInt16 (Int64 value) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Convert.cs:1093)
margaretSellTimer.OnResumeSession () (at Assets/script/margaretShop/margaretSellTimer.cs:148)
margaretSellTimer.Awake () (at Assets/script/margaretShop/margaretSellTimer.cs:28)
```

And also i try to change The line to like this :

```
TimeSpan cTime = new TimeSpan (0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt64(elapsedSeconds));
```

This also got an error :

```
Assets/script/margaretShop/margaretSellTimer.cs(148,89): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.TimeSpan.TimeSpan(int, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/script/margaretShop/margaretSellTimer.cs(148,89): error CS1503: Argument `#4' cannot convert `long' expression to type `int'
```

What i see is elapsedSeconds is to big value, so i try use ToInt64 (long) but that cant be convert like that..

Actually what i want from the cTime are like below :

```
Seconds = cTime.Seconds;
            Minutes = cTime.Minutes;
            Hours = cTime.Hours;
            days = cTime.Days;
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What type is `elapsedSeconds` and which value holds it?

Comment: it is long elapsedSeconds = Convert.ToInt64(timestamp) - oldTimestamp;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this if you just needs to build a TimeSpan from seconds :

```
TimeSpan cTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(elapsedSeconds));
```